# Как обратиться к API VK через node-vk-bot-api для просмотра последнего сообщения

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api

Пишу бота для группы VK. Необходимый функционал: "Модератор отправляет сообщение пользователю, бот его "считывает" и, если модератор написал конкретное сообщение, позволяет приступить к дальнейшим действиям."
Библиотека [node-vk-bot-api](https://github.com/node-vk-bot-api/node-vk-bot-api), как я понял, не поддерживает такого функционала(получения последнего сообщения, отправленного самим сообществом). Решил напрямую обратиться к API, но не нашёл способа. Попробовал использовать приложенный код из похожей статьи 3х-летней давности, однако он не дал никакого результата.

```js
bot.execute("messages.getHistory", {count: 1, peer_id: User_ID, start_message_id: -1}, (result) => {
    console.log('Твой результат: '+ result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил собственноручно, но не с помощью 'execute', а через XMLHttpRequest.

// *переменная request содержит [запрос к API](https://dev.vk.com/api/api-requests)*

```js
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

function reqListener () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
    }
    
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
    req.open("GET", request);
    req.send();
```